# Offline first app using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, nosql, offlineapps

I'm working on Offline first app. I have tried working on PouchDB-CouchDB but they doesn't go easy for me. Is there any middleware or something using which i can sync server SQL database to local SQL database.

Comment: 1) Should be middleware not middlewear. 2) Asking for software recommendations, tools, or other off-site resources are explicitly off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, no not really.

CouchDB / PouchDB has lots of constraints, and are trickier to use than SQL, but all those constraints exist to allow for easy replication between two nodes (in this case the browser and the server).